# Couldn't install Microsoft.WebView2 error when installing VS 2022 Community

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2022, webview2

Trying to install Visual Studio 2022 Community on a fresh installation of Windows 10 Pro with all updates installed and I get the following error:

`Couldn’t install Microsoft.WebView2`

The installer version 17.3.2. downloaded from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/

The log file from the installer:

```
Package 'Microsoft.WebView2,version=103.0.1264.37,productarch=neutral,machinearch=x64' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.WebView2;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-1073741819
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.WebView2,version=103.0.1264.37,productarch=neutral,machinearch=x64\microsoftedgewebview2runtimeinstallerx64.exe" /silent /install
        Return code: -1073741819
        Return code details: Unknown error (0xc0000005)
```

I tried this solution here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/648752/visual-studio-2022-preview-installer-error-39micro.html

First tried to run the InstallCleanup.exe in order to completely remove the installation and tried again but I got the same error

Then I tried to manually tried that setup (found at this path %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages) which was installed successfully but when retried again the installation of Visual Studio I got the same error

Then I also removed the installed Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime that was installed manually and tried again, but got the same issue

Also tried to repair any corrupted files in my system by running
`sfc /scannow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:<PATH>\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` which were completed successfully.

Same issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PackageId:MicrosoftWebView2x64;Package/1500853 and there are a lot more but with no feedback.

I have already opened a question (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Couldnt-install-MicrosoftWebView2-erro/10126180) at VS developer community but it was put "Under Consideration" today with no other feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when installing VS 2022. Setting the value in the System Registry helped

```
Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate
Value: Install = 1
```

It is Microsoft Edge Update policy and for some reason it was disabled.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#install-webview

Answer (score 0):

I could avoid this problem by simply using the full installation program which I found here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?form=MA13LH#download
instead of using the bootstrapper version.

Answer (score -1):

The same issue on my machine, I had VS 2022 professional version 17.3.2 , tried to upgrade into 17.3.3 and got same issue

Package 'Microsoft.WebView2,version=103.0.1264.37,productarch=neutral,machinearch=x64' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.WebView2;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147219198
Details
Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.WebView2,version=103.0.1264.37,productarch=neutral,machinearch=x64\microsoftedgewebview2runtimeinstallerx64.exe" /silent /install
Return code: -2147219198
Return code details: Unknown error (0x80040902)
Log
C:\Users\Hakob_Grigoryan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20220903021239_071_Microsoft.WebView2.log
Impacted workloads
Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=17.3.32708.82)
Impacted components
Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=17.3.32708.82)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).